# Anyway to set gcc to c++11 as default in terminal

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Im running through some basic exercises in c++ and some of the structures are not allowed in c++98 mode. Is there anyway I can just set gcc to always compile in c++11 and not c++98. Right now I need to add the -std=c++11 flag in terminal. I read a previous post about using a Makefile. Adding a MakeFile for every directory im running these exercises in seems a bit tedious, is there anyway around that? Im a bit new to altering my compiler so any advice would be appreciated!

Im on a windows 10 machine using powershell at the moment.

Comment: Install a more recent version of GCC? The default standard has been C++14 for like five years

Comment: You may want to upgrade your gcc compiler. You must have a very old version of gcc if it defaults to c++98.

Comment: @NathanPierson defaults to C++17 now iirc

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Ah, you're correct

Comment: You could write a Makefile and set all your wanted values in that.

Comment: I use aliases, with `c17` compiling to C++17 (the one I use most often), `c98` to C++98, `c11` to C++11 and `c20` to C++20.

Comment: You could place the command and the arguments into a batch or script file.

Comment: The g++ compiler may also accept command line parameters (or settings) in environment variables.

Comment: Or you can use CMake, to specify the c++ version in CMakeLists.txt